# Rolling average with rcpproll

Tags: r, moving-average

I have dataframe:

```
email    date_ts   total   duration

email1 2017-02-15  98.80    31990
email1 2017-02-16  59.52    60622
email1 2017-02-17  72.93    98105
email2 2017-02-18  54.45    29293
email2 2017-02-19  36.86    20157
email2 2017-02-25  18.66     7815
email2 2017-03-03   4.61     2407
email2 2017-03-04 180.91   182524
email3 2017-03-05  16.13     7121
email3 2017-03-24  25.65     2412
```

and so on...

I need calculate moving average with library RcppRoll. I try:

```
df <- df%>%group_by(email)%>%mutate(avg = roll_mean(total, 2, na.rm=TRUE, align="right", normalize = TRUE))%>%ungroup()
```

but have an error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
  incompatible size (12), expecting 13 (the group size) or 1

Answer (score 0):

Im find a solution. If you have same problem, use this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(RcppRoll)

df <- df%>%
  group_by(email)%>%
  mutate(avg = roll_mean(total, 2, na.rm=TRUE, align="right", fill = NA))%>%
  ungroup()
```